# Por qué al hacer el cast de variables me da infinito?

Tags: float, double, cast

```
public static void exercise04() {
        double bigD, normalD, smallD;
        float  bigF, normalF, smallF;
        bigD = 2.87e300;
        normalD  = 20.123456789;
        smallD  = 0.1E-200;

        bigF = (float) bigD;  
        normalF  =(float) normalD;
        smallF  = (float) smallD;


        System.out.println("Big Double : " + bigD);
        System.out.println("Big Float: " + bigF);  //POR QUÉ ESTE ME DA INFINITO????
        System.out.println("Normal Double: " + normalD);
        System.out.println("Normal Float: " + normalF);
        System.out.println("Small Double: " + smallD);
        System.out.println("Small Float: " + smallF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser porque excede el valor máximo de un float, por lo cual al convertir el dato a Float, este no puede representar el número así que lo representa como infinito positivo puesto que para un float no es finito.